# Passing values from Wordpress with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to reverse engineer a WordPress theme that uses ajax to get it's values from the database. The following is a line in a php file I found.

```
<script> 
    <span class="position-profile">{{=et_professional_title }}</span>
<script>
```

What I'm wondering is how {{=et_professional_title }} is possibly getting its value. When I do a text search on all files there about 1000 references so that won't work. Is {{ a specific syntax for something specific? I just need to be pointed in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple templating languages for WordPress. This could be Mustache or Timber (Twig).